# How to protect natural plaster in a very old house, in the bathroom

Tags: bathroom, plaster, repainting, humidity

I am finishing the last of the renovations on our house. It is an extremely old property that had not received much love for many years. My father-in-law renovated the bathroom but it has been a couple of years and the paint was peeling. I decided to fix it and while scraping the old paint, plaster started to come off. I need to know a relatively simple way of sealing and repairing the plaster so it lasts and prepares the area for painting. Thanks for taking the time to read, hope you can help. ( I am a relative novice to DIY)

Comment: Define 'extremely old'. Age seems to be very subjective. Is it protected, heritage etc? What's the construction? Is there damp? Do you have photos?